# Size for the buffer which GetUserNameEx() returns

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, unicode

I have a question about strange return sizes when calling GetUserNameEx(). Maybe someone has encountered this problem already.

I call GetUserNameEx() two times: first to get required buffer size and second to actually populate the buffer.

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can read this about the size parameter:

1. > If lpNameBuffer is too small, the function fails and GetLastError returns ERROR_MORE_DATA. This parameter receives the required buffer size, **in Unicode characters (whether or not Unicode is being used)**, including the terminating null character.

   I save this value (`required_size`) to check with the one returned on success.
2. > On input, this variable specifies the size of the lpNameBuffer buffer, in TCHARs. If the function is successful, the variable receives the number of TCHARs copied to the buffer, not including the terminating null character.

   This one is `returned_size`.

The strange thing is that if I set Character Encoding in project properties to Not Set, then `required_size` is 22 and `returned_size` is 11.

And when I set Charachter Encoding to Use Unicode Character Set, then `required_size` is 11 and `returned_size` is 11 too.

Maybe I do not get something, but I expected `required_size` not to change. Has anyone saw this already?

Thank you.

**UPD:** here is the [code example](http://pastebin.com/5Hb2x2ab).

Comment: Post your code. Would be easier to see the problem.

Comment: Updated the post with the link to the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I repro.  Well, it's a bug.  It never goes wrong because it asks for a buffer that's twice the required size.  You'll get the actual number of characters copied to the buffer on the second call so you do know the real size of the string.  I wouldn't try to fix it, there are small odds that it actually uses the buffer before converting the string from Unicode to mbcs.  Although I see no evidence of it.

Comment: Indeed. Don't make Raymond pull out his AppCompat shin again. If there's one code path on one Windows version that actually needs the oversized buffer, then you'd better provide it, even if it's not actually needed in your specific testcase, on your OS version.